# Arduino IDE не видит файлы в папках проекта

Tags: arduino-ide

Если в скетче проекта Arduino указать использование файла из другой папки этого же проекта, например `#include "src/utils.h"`, то компиляция скетча завершится ошибкой. Даже использование полного пути, например, `#include "D:/Projects/test/src/utils.h"` не помогает, результат компиляции - ошибка.

Если вытащить используемый файл из папки `src` и поместить его рядом со скетчем и, соответственно, указать `#include "utils.h"`, то компиляция пройдёт успешно.

В общем, ситуация такая - Arduino IDE не видит файлы, которые находятся в других папках этого же проекта. Но, если расположить проект в стандартной папке Arduino, типа `"C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\"`, то проект скомпилируется без ошибок.

Мне, например, нужно расположить стандартную библиотеку в своём проекте и убрать из неё лишнее, а я не могу этого сделать, т.к. Arduino IDE не видит файлы этой библиотеки.

Кто то знает, как разрешить эту ситуацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, свои локальные библиотеки и файлы, которые не хочется хранить в корне проекта, необходимо располагать в папках `src/util/` вашего проекта. Тогда компиляция пройдёт успешно